# How should I understand &**self in Box

Tags: rust

[Code in boxed.rs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.60.0/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#1762-1770):

```rust
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
#[rustc_const_unstable(feature = "const_box", issue = "92521")]
impl<T: ?Sized, A: Allocator> const Deref for Box<T, A> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        &**self
    }
}
```

In my understanding:

- `self` -> `&Box`,
- `*self` -> `Box`.
- `**self` -> `*Box`, will call: `*(Box.deref())`? Doesn't that lead to recursion?

I create a test code:

```rust
impl<T> Deref for MyBox<T> {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        &**self
    }
}
```

When I run it, Rust return me: `fatal runtime error: stack overflow`

So how does `&**self` work in std's `Box`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Box` is special. [It is a lang item](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.60.0/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#169), and the compiler knows to deref it  without help. So:

- `self` - `&Box`.
- `*self` - `Box`, builtin deref of shared reference.
- `**self` - `T`, builtin deref of `Box`.
- `&**self` - `&T`.

Similar things happen for all builtin operations. For example, [this is the `Add` impl for integers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.60.0/src/core/ops/arith.rs.html#126) (inside a macro):

```rust
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
#[rustc_const_unstable(feature = "const_ops", issue = "90080")]
impl const Add for $t {
    type Output = $t;

    #[inline]
    #[rustc_inherit_overflow_checks]
    fn add(self, other: $t) -> $t { self + other }
}
```

Again, the compiler knows to add integers. It is a builtin operation.

The reason we need the impl is for generics. Code like `0i32 + 0i32` translates to the builtin addition, but in a generic function:

```rust
fn add<T: Add>(a: T, b: T) -> T::Output { a + b }
```

If integers wouldn't implement `Add`, this function wouldn't accept them. The same happens for `Box` and `Deref`.

You can see that by inspecting the MIR. For example, the following function:

```rust
pub fn deref(b: &Box<i32>) -> &i32 {
    &**b
}
```

Generates the following MIR:

```rust
fn deref(_1: &Box<i32>) -> &i32 {
    let mut _0: &i32;
    bb0: {
        _0 = &(*(*_1));
        return;
    }
}
```

However, the following function:

```rust
pub fn deref<T: std::ops::Deref<Target = i32>>(b: &T) -> &i32 {
    &**b
}
```

Generates the following MIR, that calls `deref()`:

```
fn deref(_1: &T) -> &i32 {
    let mut _0: &i32;
    let _2: &i32;
    let mut _3: &T;
    bb0: {
        _3 = _1;
        _2 = <T as Deref>::deref(move _3) -> bb1;
    }
    bb1: {
        _0 = _2;
        return;
    }
}
```

The same happens for other `Deref` implementors, e.g. `Rc`:

```rust
pub fn deref(b: &std::rc::Rc<i32>) -> &i32 {
    &**b
}
```

```
fn deref(_1: &Rc<i32>) -> &i32 {
    let mut _0: &i32;
    let _2: &i32;
    let mut _3: &std::rc::Rc<i32>;
    bb0: {
        _3 = _1;
        _2 = <Rc<i32> as Deref>::deref(move _3) -> bb1;
    }
    bb1: {
        _0 = _2;
        return;
    }
}
```